# Flash and CORBA

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, corba

How do I get AS3 and/or Flex/AIR applications to communicate with CORBA apps?

Answer (score 2):

Until somebody writes a CORBA-compliant library for Flex (which you may care to do yourself ;), your best bet may be to build a 'wrapper' web service (accessible via the standard Flex WebService object) that acts as a bridge.

Comment: And there are tools out there that make that might make that easier, for example Apache CXF.  CXF is an open-source web services framework that also has support for REST and CORBA bindings: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-corba.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make some sort of proxy, like a Java server that you connect to. I don't think there are any CORBA libraries for AS3. I could be wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

From what I know it is possible to call Java from Flex (at least you get lot's of google results for that :-) )

Given that I would recommend to do an experiment if you can use a Java ORB (I would recommend JacORB (http://www.jacorb.org/) and see if you can use it from flex.