# Change the swing in to Flex

Tags: apache-flex, corba

My Application Architecture is below

The Solaris machine acts as Server and the server side code is in Java
The Windows machine acts as Client and the client side code is in Java Swing.

The Communication between the Server and the Client is through CORBA - Middle Level language.

I need to change my Client Side programming from Java Swing to Adobe Flex.

Is it possible to do that?

I should not disturb my Server Side Code and the MiddleLevel(CORBA) part.But only redesigning the complete client side to FLEX.

Can anyone guide me on this? I am new to Flex and i am trying to understand whether this will be possible for me to change to Flex.

Thanks in advance

Regards
S.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way would be to use a server (maybe using [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/)) as a proxy between the Flex client and the CORBA. Or maybe you could implement a CORBA API in ActionScript 3 using Sockets, but that would be a hard job I think.

If I were you, I would go with the proxy way.

By the way, it looks like [this question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338679/flash-and-corba) back in 2008, and the answer was the same.